# Weighted inputs of a neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

how can I make a NN such that some input variables are "more important" than others. For example lets say my input layer has 2 neurons and I want to stress that input one is 70% important and other one only 30% because though formula-wise they measure same thing, first one contributes more to final outcome than other. Something like weighing samples, just I want to weigh individual inputs globally.

Is that even possible/make sense?

Comment: What you are after is a weighted graph. Yes, it is possible and makes sense.

Comment: ? a neural network is weighted graph.

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150772/pybrain-how-to-print-a-network-nodes-and-weights?rq=1

Comment: What you want to do is pre-train those first two NN connections. Here is another person who appears to be looking into the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549868/pybrainhow-can-i-put-specific-weights-in-a-neural-network?rq=1

Comment: They protect the user from the internals pretty well. I think he was on the right track when he brought up the possibility of serializing, then editing the graph, as per this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006187/how-to-save-and-recover-pybrain-traning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for extending the connections and layers in pybrain:

http://www.pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/extending-structure.html

It appears that you should be able to create connections from your input nodes with the desired behavior as subclasses of the connection object.

Then you put pieces together:

http://www.pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html#netmodcon

Attaching your two input modules with instances of the weighted connection to your module.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial [How to measure importance of inputs?](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ayhYe72_20OoJ%3aftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/importance.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)

> Terms such as "importance," "saliency," and "sensitivity" do not have
>   precise, widely-accepted meanings. This answer will discuss a variety
>   of methods that have been proposed to measure the importance of
>   inputs, but the list is by no means exhaustive. Different measures of
>   importance are likely to be useful in different applications of neural
>   nets. The main point of this answer is that there is no single measure
>   of importance that is appropriate for all applications.